# How to make UISegmentedcontrol transparent?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Does anybody know how to make `UISegmentedControl` transparent?  I set the background Theme of the `ViewController` and the text color. I am currently using this code in `ViewDidLoad`:

```
segGame.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.4];
```

Is there any way to set `segmentedControl` programmatically or in xib's?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make custom segment controller.

Write this code in your `ViewDidLoad` method. No problem

Please try this one:

```
// Set set segmentControl background to transparent

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
UIImage *transparentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[segmentControl setBackgroundImage:transparentImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentControl setDividerImage:transparentImage forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

If you use image for this one, then its looks better than background transparency

```
  [segmentControl setDividerImage:[UIImage new] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
  [segmentControl setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Try this one.

Comment: Is there any way to set segmentedControl transparent in xib's?

Comment: Follow this link: http://www.framewreck.net/2010/07/custom-tintcolor-for-each-segment-of.html

Comment: in xib it's already coming with transparent. which xcode u r using?

Comment: I got my answer But it's only work in IOS 7. I set background color is clear color and set tint color =

Answer (score -1):

[image: You can choose any colour for background in storyboard]

Storyboard is very handy for what you want to do. look at screnshot.